# What is linear interpolation?

Tags: interpolation

I am learning about linear interpolation however, we were not taught how to formally solve a problem using linear interpolation. A practice problem involving is the following:

Find how long it will take for a certain sum of money to double itself at compound annual interest of 20%. Solve this problem. Then solve this problem by first finding $(1.2)^3$ and $(1.2)^4$ and then by linear interpolation, approximating $x$ such that $(1.2)^x=2$. Show the result so obtained is equal to the Mesopotamian solution expressed sexagesimally as 3;47,13,20.

Answer (score 1):

In linear interpolation, you have two points on the curve and draw a straight line through them.  You use that line to approximate the value at other points of the curve.  Your two points are $(3,y_1)$ and $(4,y_2)$, where you are supposed to calculate $y_1,y_2$.  Then you use the two-point form of the line $y-y_1=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)$ to find the $x$ where $y=2$

Comment: Is y=2 the answer to my specific problem or is it a generalization in order to find the answer to the problem

Comment: $y=2$ is what you are looking for because that represents doubling of the original principal.  Your $y$ values are the ratio of the current value to the original.

Comment: Okay, I see now where the 3 and 4 come into play with the x-values. Now why does it want to ask to find (1.2)^3 and (1.2)^4 first though, what are we finding with those numbers?

Comment: You are finding two points on the curve that bracket the point of interest.  You won't have $y_1,y_2$ without that.  The curve is an exponential.  I suggest you graph it over $[1,1.5]$, plot these points, draw the straight line through them, then graph it over $[1.2,1.3]$, plot the points and the straight line.  It will help you see what is happening.  The straight line is an approximation to the curve.

Comment: I have graphed the points and the curve to see it

Comment: The point is that the straight line is what your interpolation will follow.  It is pretty close, but not exact.  Suppose you have a function that is very expensive to calculate, but you need values at lots of points.  You might choose to calculate it at a number of points, tabulate them, and use linear interpolation between.  Of course, having more points makes the interpolation more accurate, but it takes a bigger table.  That is the point of the exercise.